# Check if data that satisfies multiple criteria exists in both sheet 1 and sheet 2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My table contains 2 sheets with a different number of columns. I want to add a column that will display true or false (or any other 2 opposite values ) for each row depending on whether this row satisfies 2 criteria which are: `sheet1!col1=sheet2!col1` and `sheet1!col2=sheet2!col2`.

You'll find an illustration below. 
I've tried using

```
ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1&B1, {Sheet1!A1:A4&Sheet1!B1:B4,Sheet1!C1}, 3))
```

but I get an error message

> vlookup evaluates to an out of bound range

So I wanted to try

```
QUERY({Sheet1!A1:B4,A1:B5}, "Select C where ")
```

but I couldn't figure out how to write the condition `where (sheet1)col1=(sheet2)col1 & (sheet1)col2=(sheet2)col2` and I also don't know if I can work with tables of different dimensions. I finally tried

```
=MATCH(A1&B1,{Sheet1!A1:A&Sheet1!B1:B})
```

but it always returns 1.
Any idea please?

Sheet 1
 [image: sheet1]

Sheet 2
[image: sheet2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first formula is almost right. You are getting the error message because there is only one column in the curly brackets so you have to change it to

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A1&B1,{Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B},1,false))
```

and add the 'false' to make sure it only does exact matches.

To make the query work you need the right syntax to access cells in the current sheet:

```
=query(Sheet2!A:B," select A,B where A='"&A1&"' and B='"&B1&"'")
```

To make the match work, you need to enter it as an array formula and add a zero to specify exact match:

```
=ArrayFormula(MATCH(A1&B1,{Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B},0))
```

However I would take flak from my colleagues if I didn't point out that there is an issue with the vlookup and match as shown above - toto&moto would match with not just toto&moto, but also with tot&omoto etc. The way round this is to add a separator character e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A1&"|"&B1,{Sheet2!A:A&"|"&Sheet2!B:B},1,false))

=ArrayFormula(MATCH(A1&"|"&B1,{Sheet2!A:A&"|"&Sheet2!B:B},0))
```

These still need some tidying up if they are to report Yes and No, and also not to give false positive on blank rows - also the vlookup and match can be written as self-expanding array formulas - but that is the short answer to the question.